# Name of this operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Given two tuples $A = \langle a_1, \dots, a_n \rangle$ and $B = \langle b_1, \dots, b_m \rangle$, let $A\oplus B \stackrel{def}{=} \langle (a_1+b_1), \dots, (a_1+b_m), (a_2+b_1), \dots, (a_2+b_m), \dots, (a_n+b_m) \rangle$, where $+$ is just the addition (e.g. over $N$). Is there a known name for the operation $\oplus$ defined in this way ?

Thank you !

Comment: The direct sum.

Comment: But I think the direct sum would not have a component for which subscripts were mixed in the sum.

Comment: Note that the symbol you've chosen to denote the operation is misleading, because the operation is *not* commutative: the first tuple is "major", the second is "minor".

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize \oplus typically refers to commutative operations; if you could suggest a more suitable symbol, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @AntonBelov There isn't really a reason $\oplus$ should denote a commutative operation, but if you used plain $+$ then it would be misleading.